# A fantastic junk-creature at the bottom of the sea

Tags: story-identification, magical-creatures

This Fantasy novelette is at least 20 years old, maybe more. Which shows that the problem of the pollution of the oceans has been known for a long time.

It takes place on an island in the Caribbeans, famous for its coral reefs. But in fact the bottom of the ocean is mostly covered with junk. The POV character is a newcomer tourist, a scuba-diver who befriends an old hand scuba-diver (not exactly a local, IIRC, just someone familiar to that place) who tells him an incredible story.

Once he went scuba-diving, not alone (he was serious about following security rules). The party saw mostly junk but somehow chanced onto a preserved area. And too concentrated on the beauty there, the speaker got separated from the remainder of the party. While trying to catch up with them, he went again through a junk-filled area. There he saw a gigantic woman on the floor of the sea. Getting nearer he sees that it was in fact a mass of junk, each body part being just a different piece of junk. **But** this construct was **alive** ! It (she ?) stretched its (her ?) arms to catch him ! He barely managed to escape. Totally lost, at night in the middle of the ocean, he was saved by a passing boat.

Of course one **could** rationalise the whole thing by claiming that was just a hallucination of a scuba-diver exhausted by too long a dive, and afraid he was lost (which he was). But the obvious intent of the author was that he deliberately meant the ambiguity, fantasy vs hallucination. And the editor of the collection clearly agreed with that.

Comment: I'm sure I've read this, and I think it's by a well known author. But the way I remember it the diver is admiring the beauty of the reef, but then looks more closely and suddenly notices all the trash. It's a revelation to him just how badly the reef is polluted. Then he sees the woman.

Comment: @JohnRennie   As I remember there is really a small patch which is very beautiful, and this is how the diver got separated from the others. Trying to catch up, he soon gets into a trash filled zone, and  indeed then sees the woman. But you might be right. I read it long ago, so I am not sure.

Comment: Found it. Thanks goodness, this has been bugging me for days :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Beyond the Dead Reef](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49102) by James Tiptree Jr. I have just found it in The Year's Best Science Fiction First Annual Collection, though I am not sure if that's where I first read it.

The story is as you remember. The diver says:

> "The reef was live here—whatever had killed the coral hadn’t reached yet, and the damned basura had quit or been deflected, aside from a beer bottle or two. There was life everywhere; anemones, sponges, conches, fans, stars—and fish, oh my! No one ever came here, you see. In fact, there didn’t seem to have been any spearing, the fish were as tame as they used to be years back."
>
> "Well, we began zigzagging back and forth, just revelling in it. And every time we’d meet head-on we’d make the gesture of putting our fingers to our lips, meaning Don’t tell anyone about this, ever!"

The diver gets lost because he follows what turns out to be a large fish that looked like his companion:

> "I had been following a goddamned great fish—a fish with a bright blue and orange band around its belly, and a thin white body ending in a black, flipperlike tail. Even its head and nape were black, like her hair and mask. It had a repulsive catfishlike mouth, with barbels."

And it's then that he sees the woman on the sea bed:

> "Again I was mistaken, you see. It wasn’t Ann at all; but the rather more distant figure of a young woman, of truly enormous size. All in this great ridge of graveyard luminosity, of garbage in phosphorescent decay. The current was carrying me slowly, inexorably, right toward her—as it had carried all that was there now. And perhaps I was also a bit hypnotized. She grew in my sight meter by meter as I neared her. I
> think six meters—eighteen feet—was about it, at the end … I make that guess later, you understand, as an exercise in containing the unbearable—by recalling the size of known items in the junkpile she lay on. One knee, for example, lay alongside an oil drum. At the time she simply filled my world. I had no doubt she was dead, and very beautiful. One of her legs seemed to writhe gently."

And then:

> "It wasn’t merely that as I floated over her horrible eyes ‘opened’ and looked at me, and her rusted-can mouth smiled. Oh, no."
>
> "What I mean is that as she smiled, first one whole arm, shedding junk, stretched up and reached for me against the current, and then the other did the same. And when I proved to be out of reach, this terrifying figure, or creature, or unliving life, actually sat up, again against the current, and reached up toward me with both arms at full extension."

Comment: Exactly what I remembered !